# How to override values if possible in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I try to store the working hours of employees in a mysql table. In the table `working_hour` i store the normal working hours:

```
id employee weekDay    start     end 
1     1       2      10:00:00  18:00:00
2     1       3      10:00:00  18:00:00
3     1       4      10:00:00  14:00:00
4     1       5      10:00:00  12:00:00
5     1       6      10:00:00  18:00:00
6     1       7      00:00:00  00:00:00
7     1       1      00:00:00  00:00:00
```

In a 2nd table i store "special" working hours. There i store things like illness, holidays or just customized working hours for a specific day. The `working_hour_specia`l table look like:

```
id           start                   end            type
2     12013-03-12 00:00:00  2013-03-13 23:59:59      ill
```

And thats what i have tried:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(working_hour_special.start, working_hour.start) AS startTime,
    IFNULL(working_hour_special.end, working_hour.end) AS endTime,
    type
FROM 
    working_hour_special LEFT JOIN
    working_hour ON working_hour.employee_id = working_hour_special.employee_id
WHERE 
    working_hour_special.start = DATE('2013-03-13') AND 
    employee_id = 1 AND
    working_hour.weekDay = DAYOFWEEK('2013-03-13')
```

The problem is the WHERE-Clause. I need the start and end time of a specific day for a specific employee. Got somebody an idea how to do that?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? And what's wrong?

Comment: How do you match dates from `working_hour_special` to `working_hour`?

Comment: @Obl Tobl:I try zo get the working hours for a specific employee. If there is no "special", like illness or holidays i need the normal working hours for a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it appears poor table design.  You have just a day of week in one, but a full date/time stamp in the other.  Nothing to differentiate betweek day of week 1 for the January 1st week, vs day of week 1 in week of July 26th.

Second, when you have a left-join, and then throw that table into a WHERE clause (without consideration test of a NULL), it basically creates a normal INNER JOIN.

So, what you may be looking for is to shift your WHERE component associated with the SPECIAL to the JOIN part of the condition... something like.

```
SELECT 
      IFNULL(working_hour_special.start, working_hour.start) AS startTime,
      IFNULL(working_hour_special.end, working_hour.end) AS endTime,
      type
   FROM 
      working_hour_special 
         LEFT JOIN working_hour 
            ON working_hour.employee_id = working_hour_special.employee_id
           AND working_hour_special.start = DATE('2013-03-13')
   WHERE 
          employee_id = 1 
      AND working_hour.weekDay = DAYOFWEEK('2013-03-13')
```

Comment: Which table design would be better? I need to store normal working hours and also need to store additional information like illness or holidays.

Comment: @ThomasSchiela, I would have all in one with a column for a status such as to indicate regular time, over time, illness, holiday, whatever.  Also, have full date/time vs day of week.  You can always compute day of week from the date.  Then the query is all from one table working or not.

Comment: to store all information in one table was my first idea. But i thoughted i got to many records for many employees (~1000), becouse i need the information for the next 2-3 Month. With two tables i only store the "standard" week and store some additional "special" days.

Comment: @ThomasSchiela, SQL (MySQL and others) when designed well, and with proper indexes to match context of query WHERE clauses are no problem, even with millions of records.  So, really split things up and make messy, or let the engine handle it better for you.